# Return multiple types from c++ method?

Tags: c++, generics, if-statement, return-value

Is it possible for a function in c++ to return multiple types. For instance,

```
"return multiple types" getType( string choice )
{
     if(choice == "A"){
        ObjectA obj;
          return obj;
     }
     if(choice == "B"){
        ObjectB obj;
          return obj;
     }
     else
        return nullPtr;

}
```

Here, `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` are two different types. Based on user selection, either type of Object is returned. Is this even possible ? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**The method would be used as follows

```
template <typename T>
void doStuff(T thing)
{
    cout << thing.num << endl;
}
```

Usage

```
 doStuff(getType(selection));
```

Both `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` would contain a public variable called `num`.

Comment: How would you hope to *use* the return value from this function?

Comment: you might try `boost::variant`

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The value returned would be plugged into function which has a template parameter.

Comment: But what type would you assign the return value to?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No clear on what you mean ? Both ObjectA and ObjectB have same methods that does different things..so the template parameters method is called.

Comment: I mean, you're going to be doing something like `SomeType x = getType(someString);`, right?  What type is `SomeType`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Check question again..I updated with an example of usage.

Comment: I don't see how that demonstrates usage of `getType`...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, I forgot to write one line with everything together.

Comment: Ok, but you realise that templates are processed at *compile*-time, right?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, and I don't think it is an issue for what I am working on.

Comment: Of course it is ;)  You're expecting your code to pick a template instance based on something that's only known at *run-time*.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth What is wrong with that ?

Comment: As I said, templates are instantiated at *compile-time*.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Please tell me why it is an issue that templates are instantiated at run time ? And do you have an answer to my original question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply not possible.

C++ is not a scripting language, and is static-typed with no reflection. A function return type (like a variable type) must be compile-time defined, and cannot depend on the run-time execution.

What you can do is let `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` to have a common polymorphic base and return a pointer or reference to it: the static type will be that common base, and the runtime-type will be the actual object (it will respond to virtual functions and can be reached by `dynamic_cast`)

Alternatively you can use a "type cancellation" technique (like boost::any), which essentially wraps the static typed object into another object having a common base managed by a handler.

In any case a somewhat runtime-type polymorphism (in the object or in the wrapper) is needed.

Comment: I suppose I must change my application structure to avoid this scenario. Thanks for the clarification !

Answer (score 0):

Return a pointer whatever the object, then you can do any type-checking elsewhere.